# Java handle Private Method/Object in a Library

Tags: java, gwt, overriding

I am using [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/overview.html) and would like to call the `Popup.Hide()` method in the Library class `MenuBar` but it is private and the Object is private too...

so what is the best way to get the method:

1. If I create a complete new class which inherits from `MenuBar`, will not work I have to create 10 other classes which depend on the `MenuBar`, for example `MenuItem`, since `MenuItem`s also hold private static variables, which seems too involved.
2. unzip the .jar and change the method to public.
3. another way?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I may be mistaken but do you mean PopupPanel.hide()?

Comment: What is `Popup` here? Please post a sample code.

Comment: Do you mean by removing/hiding a menu item from the menu bar?

Comment: Don't do that. Describe what you're trying to accomplish instead.

Comment: My MenuBar opens the Submenus whenim hovering but when i leave it, the Submenu is still visible

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3860

Answer (score 0):

there's no Hide() uppercase method in java, did you read the javadoc? hide() is also a lowercase method. Do you use eclipse with the Google plugin?

```
Button b1 = new Button("Click me to show popup");
b1.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    // Instantiate the popup and show it.
    new MyPopup().show();
  }
});
```

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html